# how to form a 64bit number using 2 pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have two pointers

```
uint64_t* ptr1;
uint64_t* ptr2;
```

I have to form a var value such that 6 bytes are taken from ptr1 and 2 bytes from ptr2 and currently ptr1 has consumed its initial 2 bytes and now the remaining bytes left to be processed is 6 bytes.

I wrote something like this

```
uint64_t value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1) >> 16);\
value = (uint64_t)(value << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff));\
```

Ideally its the mask should be 0xffff000000000000, but it doesn't work.(For processing purposes). How should I proceed and what am I doing wrong here?
According to me it should just be

```
value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff)  << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0xffff000000000000));
```

EDIT: ptr1 here points to (uint8_t*)ptr1 +2, i.e 2 bytes after ptr1

Comment: First do `const uint64_t x = *ptr1, y = *ptr2;`, and now you no longer have two pointers. I'm just trying to say that the pointers themselves are not the interesting thing here.

Comment: Which 6 bytes from `*ptr1` and which 2 bytes from `*ptr2`?  From the question it sounds like you want the 6 lower-order bytes from the first and the 2 highest-order bytes from the second.  Is that the case?  And are you taking endianness into account?

Comment: Exactly. I also wanted to know if endianness matters during masking?

Comment: Only this is working - uint64_t value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1 >> 16) << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff));

Comment: Endian'ness does NOT matter when masking a value.

Comment: This is the kind of code you'd write when you forgot to declare a *struct*.

Comment: means? Please explain?

Comment: @user3629249 Endian-ness may make a difference here as OP says "initial 2 bytes".  If by "initial", OP means the bytes in lowest memory, then endian-ness is critical.  If by "initial", OP means the least significant (or most significant) bytes, then endian-ness does not matter.  So, IDK, please detail what you mean by "initial bytes"

Comment: I do mean the least significant bytes.

Comment: @IDK, "2 least significant bytes" is clearer than "initial 2" bytes.  So endian-ness does not matter in this post.

Answer (score 1):

First write the mask

```
#define mask 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Extract 6 bytes out of `ptr1` and store them

```
const uint64_t first_six = *ptr1 & mask;
```

Extract 2 bytes out of `ptr2` and store them

```
const uint16_t last_two = *ptr2 & 0xFFFFull;
```

Finally, put them together

```
uint64_t value = (first_six << 16) | last_two;
```

In a single expression

```
uint64_t value = ( (*ptr1 & mask) << 16 ) | (*ptr2 & 0xFFFFull);
```

> I also wanted to know if endianness matters during masking?

Endianness has no importance in this case.

Comment: Only this is working - uint64_t value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1 >> 16) << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff)). So I thought endianness could be the issue?

Comment: Endianness is to be considered when you're looking at the *layout* of  data; whenever you apply actual operations on it you need not. You don't consider endianness when you do `4 + 4`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here, your question is somewhat vague... but I'll try, as far as I understand:

Your last line

```
value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff)  << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0xffff000000000000));
```

does this: it extracts the top 48 bits of *ptr1, and multiplies the result by 2^16. The result is a number that contains the middle 32 bits of *ptr1, shifted to its top 32 bits. Then you extract the top 16 bits from *ptr2 and or that to this first value. Your result will be within the top 32 bits of the combined value, with bits from *ptr2 directly being or'ed with bits from *ptr1. You probably mean to do something like this:

```
value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1  >> 16) | (*ptr2 & 0xffff000000000000));
```

which would combine the low 48 bits of *ptr1 with the high 16 bits of *ptr2, or

```
value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff) | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff));
```

which combines the high 48 bits of *ptr1 with the low 48 bits of *ptr2, or maybe even

```
value = (uint64_t)((*ptr1  >> 16) | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff) << 48);
```

which would place the top 48 bits of *ptr1 at the bottom of the new value, and the bottom 16 bits of *ptr2 in the top 16 bits of the result.

Comment: With 32-bit `int/unsigned`, `~0x000000000000ffff` --> `0x00000000ffff0000`, not `0xffffffffffff0000`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(uint64_t)((*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff)  << 16 | (*ptr2 & 0xffff000000000000));
```

Taken an expression at a time:

```
(*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff)
```

results in `12 34 56 78 9a bc 00 00`

```
12 34 56 78 9a bc 00 00  << 16
```

results in  `56 78 9a bc 00 00 00 00`

```
(*ptr2 & 0xffff000000000000))
```

results in `12 34 00 00 00 00 00 00`

```
56 78 9a bc 00 00 00 00 | 12 23 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

results in `?? ?? 9a bc 00 00 00 00`

which is not appending the first 6 bytes of `*ptr1` with the last 2 bytes of `*ptr2`

I suggest

```
(uint64_t)((*ptr1 & ~0x000000000000ffff)  | (*ptr2 & 0x000000000000ffff));
```

Comment: Thanks for the visual explanation! and it works too!

Comment: Suspicious about `~0x000000000000ffff` Try `printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof(0x000000000000ffff)); printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof(~0x000000000000ffff));`  Certain code should be `~((uint64_t)0x000000000000ffff)`.

Comment: It was working because last bytes were same as first two bytes. I want last 6 bytes of ptr1 with first two of ptr2.

Answer (score 0):

OP is incorrectly attempting to make a 64-bit mask from a too narrow constant.

On a machine with less than 64-bit `int/unsigned` `0x000000000000ffff` is a constant of width "less-than 64".  On a 32-bit machine,  `~0x000000000000ffff` --> `0xffff0000` and not the hoped for `0xffffffffffff0000`

Appending `LL` will insure the constant is at least 64-bit.

To implement "form a var value such that 6 bytes are taken from ptr1 and 2 bytes from ptr2"

```
#define BYTES7TO2_MASK (0xffffffffffff0000)
#define BYTES1TO0_MASK (0xffff)
value = ((*ptr1 & BYTES7TO2_MASK) >> 16) || ((*ptr2 & BYTES1TO0_MASK) << (64-16));
```